# angular-cli ng serve : Error: No errors

Tags: angular-cli

I just tried to create a new project with angular-cli, then running the server but it halts with a fun message : `Error: No errors` .

I updated it this way (hoping it helps) : `npm uninstall -g angular-cli ; npm cache clean ; npm install -g angular-cli@latest`

But it is same issue. See all messages here : http://pastebin.com/AhbdHRR7

Fortunalty, my other projects are still working.

But what happens for a new one ?

JPM

```
node -v ==> v6.9.4
npm -v ==> 4.1.2
ng version ==> angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.26
```

Comment: ng build has the same issue ... it is not connected only to serve command

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to this [bug report](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4264) you need to install an extra dependency.

```
npm install extract-text-webpack-plugin@2.0.0-rc.0 --save-dev
```

Which made it work for me.

Comment: Pretty sloppy stuff from the angular team. Even the boiler plate "ng new" apps fail to start due to this.

Comment: I don't think this is an angular bug.  The bug report referenced indicates that this is caused by the external dependency.  Thanks @KIC, this worked for me.